# PHP array data displaying incorrectly

Tags: php, arrays

I am currently building a like system for users that post a status. I have the following code to display the 'likes' on each of the status posts:

```
/* GET THE STATUS LIKE DETAILS */
$qryNumLikes = mysqli_query($redoDB, "SELECT likestatUID,likestatMName FROM statLike WHERE likeStatPostID = '".$statRow['statID']."'");
$numLikes = mysqli_num_rows($qryNumLikes);
while($likeRow = $qryNumLikes->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $name[] = $likeRow['likestatMName'];
    $nameid[] = $likeRow['likestatUID'];
}
if($numLikes > 0){
    if($numLikes == 1){                     
        if(in_array($memID, $nameid)){
            $showLikes = 'You like this.';
        } else {
            $showLikes = $name[0].' likes this.';
        }
    } elseif($numLikes == 2) {
        if(in_array($memID, $nameid)){
            if(($key = array_search($memName, $name)) !== false) {
                unset($name[$key]);
            }
            $names = array_values($name);
            $showLikes = 'You and '.$names[0].' like this.';
        } else {
            $showLikes = $name[0].' and '.$name[1].' like this.';
        }
    } elseif($numLikes == 3) {
        if(in_array($memID, $nameid)){
            if(($key = array_search($memName, $name)) !== false) {
                unset($name[$key]);
            }
            $names = array_values($name);
            $showLikes = $names[0].', '.$names[1].' and you like this.';
        } else {
            $showLikes = $name[0].', '.$name[1].' and '.($numLikes - 2).' other like this.';
        }
    } else {
        if(in_array($memID, $nameid)){
            if(($key = array_search($memName, $name)) !== false) {
                unset($name[$key]);
            }
            $names = array_values($name);
            $showLikes = 'You, '.$names[0].' and '.($numLikes - 2).' others like this.';
        } else {
            $showLikes = $name[0].', '.$name[1].' and '.($numLikes - 2).' others like this.';
        }
    }
} else {
    $showLikes = $numLikes.' Likes';
}
```

Status One is 'liked' by user IDs 1 and 2 and the array data is as follows:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 )
```

Status Two is 'liked' by user ID 1 only and the array data is as follows:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 1 )
```

As you can see this is incorrect and it should only display Array ( [0] => 1 ). For the life of me I can not figure out why this is happening. The result is that when user ID 2 is looking at the displayed likes it says "You like this' when it should read 'User ID 1 Likes this' (the name of course).

Can anyone tell me where the code is going wrong please?

Many thanks.

Comment: can you add var_dump($name);var_dump($nameid); between the while and the if? And let us know what was the output, if it still didn't help you enough :)

Comment: @Gavriel - Thanks but I have answered below. This seems to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I just needed to declare the arrays first. (been trying to figure this out for hours and then succeed after posting here, typical).

```
$name = array();
$nameid = array();
```

Added that before the while loop.